# Gravity Forms Action URL changes

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I currently have a gravity form in a template calculator.php file. The gravity form works as expected in preview mode and redirects the user to another page /results on form submission.

However since placing this form in my php template file, it instead of redirecting to the confirmation url: /results, it returns the entire calculator.php file inside of the div!!

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php                    
                gravity_form(5, false, false, false, '', True);
                ?>
            </div>
```

[image: Form before pressing get report]

[image: calculator.php is now returned on top of the form, along with all of the code instead of redirecting to the specified url]

Comment: Probably because you are using AJAX (sixth parameter set to true), in that case it takes the response and inserts it into the current document.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I tried that it is no longer returning the start page (index.php) inside of the div.

There is still an issue: It's redirecting back to index.php entirely and not to the /results page. Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you set that redirect up? Does it need to be `/results/` maybe, or an absolute URL?